bypass server configuration and hit on ip directly
we are using ip tables to only allow connection coming to the server from cloudflare proxy , and deny others .
and we have set up the named_conf to no recursion , enabled syn cookie and these stuff .
yet , hits on the ip managed to arrive and killing the server , the strange thing is our server was sending attacks as well when it was attacked !
so we fresh installed the  software , once it connected to internet it happens again and start to send attacks while it is being attacked as well .
we suspect reflection or amplification attack , we did what we know to secure but unfortuanlly that doesn't work ..
here is what we did :
iptables :
# Flush existing rules
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X

# Allow all loopback (lo) traffic and drop all traffic to 127.0.0.0/8 that doesn't use lo
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Cloudflare IP ranges
iptables -A INPUT -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 104.16.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 104.24.0.0/14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s **** -j ACCEPT

# telegram 
iptables -A INPUT -s 91.108.56.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 91.108.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 91.108.8.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 91.108.16.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 91.108.12.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 149.154.160.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 91.105.192.0/23 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 91.108.20.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 185.76.151.0/24 -j ACCEPT



# Allow established and related connections
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow important WHM and cPanel ports from Cloudflare only
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 104.16.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 104.24.0.0/14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083,2082,2086,2095,2096 -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT

# Allow MySQL and Redis connections from localhost only
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP and HTTPS from Cloudflare only
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 104.16.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 104.24.0.0/14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 104.16.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 104.24.0.0/14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SMTP and email traffic (Microsoft 365 IPs and ports) for IPv4
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 13.107.6.152/31 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 13.107.18.10/31 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 13.107.128.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 23.103.160.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 40.96.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 40.104.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 52.96.0.0/14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 131.253.33.215/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 132.245.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 150.171.32.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -s 204.79.197.215/32 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH with connection limit from Cloudflare only
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 3 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --name sshguard --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --name sshguard --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 104.16.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 104.24.0.0/14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT

# Allow all traffic from localhost (127.0.0.1)
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT

# ICMP protection: Allow ping from Cloudflare only and drop others
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 104.16.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 104.24.0.0/14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP

# TCP flags protection
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP

# Protect against common protocols that should not be exposed
iptables -A INPUT -p esp -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p ah -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p ipip -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p gre -j DROP

# Limit connections per IP (except for localhost)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-above 100 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

# UDP flood protection (except for localhost)
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 25 -m recent --name UDP-FLOOD --set
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 25 -m recent --name UDP-FLOOD --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 50 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m recent --name UDP-FLOOD --set
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m recent --name UDP-FLOOD --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 50 -j DROP

# SYN flood protection (except for localhost)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 5/s --limit-burst 10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j DROP

# ICMP flood protection (except for localhost)
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT

# Port scanning protection (except for localhost)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

# Limit new connections (except for localhost)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 15 --hitcount 50 -j DROP

# log 
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
# Set default policies
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Save rules
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables

other securing options we tried :
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2

# TIME-WAIT sockets recycling
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1

# Increase size of connection tracking table
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 2000000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 600

# Disable ICMP redirects
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0

# Enable reverse path filtering
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1

# Increase the backlog queue
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536

# Increase TCP read/write memory buffers
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216

# Enable TCP Fast Open
net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen = 3

# Adjust TCP keepalive parameters
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 10
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 6
sysctl -p

options {
...
recursion no;
allow-query { none; };
...
};
sample of attack on server :
> Threshold Flows 200 flows/s
> Sum 139,479 flows/300s (464 flows/s), 697,485,000 packets/300s (2,324,950 packets/s), 38.904 GByte/300s (1,062 MBit/s)
> External 4.7.11.22, 3 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 25,000 packets/300s (83 packets/s), 0.002 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
> External 177.233.2.42, 3 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 25,000 packets/300s (83 packets/s), 0.004 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
> External 189.204.72.33, 3 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 20,000 packets/300s (66 packets/s), 0.003 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
> External 154.54.88.226, 2 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 20,000 packets/300s (66 packets/s), 0.002 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
> External 17.94.17.63, 2 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 10,000 packets/300s (33 packets/s), 0.001 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)


sample attacks out :
> Threshold Packets 300,000 packets/s
> Sum 96,545,000 packets/300s (321,816 packets/s), 19,309 flows/300s (64 flows/s), 3.954 GByte/300s (107 MBit/s)
> External 181.132.189.101, 10,000 packets/300s (33 packets/s), 2 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 0.000 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
> External 81.106.215.61, 10,000 packets/300s (33 packets/s), 2 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 0.000 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
> External 158.83.29.54, 10,000 packets/300s (33 packets/s), 2 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 0.000 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
> External 52.43.148.225, 5,000 packets/300s (16 packets/s), 1 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 0.000 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)


we scanned for malware and did everything we could think of , nothing solves the issue .
we use hetzner dedected hosting
sometimes server falls with error : handshake failed while being attacked without increasing in the load at all
any advices ?

while being attacked without increasing in the load at all while firewall on a host itself can be used to "hide" services on the host, it doesn't mean that the host itself is hidden. If its public IP is known by the attacker, the host is not "hidden", so is not the network link.

what to do then ?

Is 'iptables -A INPUT -s **** -j ACCEPT' a stand-in for other IP addresses or exactly what you have down there.  I suspect if its actually written like that it might be allowing everything through?    Also, if you run 'iptables -vnL' this will show you what rules are being hit which might give you some clues if its an issue with iptables?

stands for other ip address , command shows correct rules , idk how is he bypassing

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 5/s --limit-burst 10 -j ACCEPT Do note that with the way you write your table, this rule would allow ANY host to send a TCP SYN (i.e. initiate TCP connection/communication). Subsequent traffics of the same connections are not bound by the limit in this rule.

NOTE: This answer purely attempts to explain how iptables work. The author does NOT imply that a firewall on the host itself is sufficient to deal the type of attack in concern.
When you filter traffics with iptables (or really any firewall), you can't just throw different kinds rules into it and expect it to magically work as desired. You need to be aware of and understand how the filtering works.
When a packet enter the firewall, it traverses respective base chains in multiple tables, and it is matched against each rule in each chain, until there is no more rule or it is made to stop traversing the current base chain further by a terminating target, such as ACCEPT, DROP or REJECT. The fate of packets that have not come across such target will be governed the chain policy.
In your filter/INPUT, while its policy is DROP, there is no rule that universally drops all types of packet or all TCP packet. While there is a rule that drops all TCP SYN packet:
-p tcp --syn -j DROP

the rule is appended (-A) to the table after:
-p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 5/s --limit-burst 10 -j ACCEPT

which means TCP SYN packets from ANY host would be accepted, before the limits are reached.
Note that I do NOT mean that you should swap the order of these two rules. That is not at all my point. What I mean is, the earlier ACCEPT rules that you have for Cloudflare IP ranges whatsoever do not imply that traffics that are not matched / covered by them would be automagically dropped. Also, this SYN flood protection will not be applied to TCP traffics that are unconditionally (well, I mean like the with no more conditions other than -s and maybe --dport) accepted by earlier rules.
You should really re-structure your table with some "layered" user-defined chains. For example, assuming you still want SYN flood protection for Cloudflare IP ranges et al.:
# Flush the filter table
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Allow all loopback (lo) traffic and drop all traffic to 127.0.0.0/8 that doesn't use lo
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

## this rule should be appended as early as possible for performance concern
## you may even place it before the lo-related ones above
# Allow established and related connections
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# chain for handling "selected" TCP traffics
iptables -N TCP

# SYN flood protection (except for localhost)
iptables -A TCP -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 5/s --limit-burst 10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A TCP -p tcp --syn -j DROP

# This accepts "non-SYN" packets, if any;
# You may really want to DROP or REJECT them instead
iptables -A TCP -j ACCEPT

# But if so, more ideally you would want do it earlier
# (i.e., in INPUT):
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -j DROP
# with the above rule you can even eliminate
# the -p tcp --syn matches in the "SYN flood protection" rules

# packet that is made to traverse this chain will be dropped
# if its source address is not is one of the allowed; those
# that are not dropped will be made to continue traversal
# in the chain it jumped from (e.g., INPUT or ALLOW_TCP)
iptables -N ALLOW_ALL
iptables -A ALLOW_ALL -s 1.2.3.4 -j RETURN
iptables -A ALLOW_ALL -s 2.3.4.5 -j RETURN
iptables -A ALLOW_ALL -j DROP

# list of sources from which only TCP traffics are allowed;
# packets from them are made to traverse the TCP handling chain
iptables -N ALLOW_TCP
iptables -A ALLOW_TCP -s 3.4.5.6 -j TCP
iptables -A ALLOW_TCP -s 4.5.6.7 -p tcp --dport 22 -j TCP
iptables -A ALLOW_TCP -s 5.6.7.8 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j TCP
# if you don't want "special handling" set up in the TCP chain
# for certain sources, just early accept it:
iptables -A ALLOW_TCP -s 192.168.1.123 -j ACCEPT

# note how ALLOW_ALL is designed and used to avoid unnecessarily
# repeating -s matches; also these pair of rules must be the
# latest rules in ALLOW_TCP:
iptables -A ALLOW_TCP -j ALLOW_ALL
iptables -A ALLOW_TCP -j TCP

# with -g, no TCP traffics would be matched by later rules in INPUT;
# TCP packets that do not have decided fate yet will have their fate
# determined by the chain policy of INPUT. However, as per the
# rules / design of our user-defined chains, there will be no such
# packet
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -g ALLOW_TCP

# Come up with similar chains and rules for UDP and ICMP yourself

# If you want to allow traffics of unlikely protocols from source
# listed in ALLOW_ALL:
iptables -A INPUT -j ALLOW_ALL
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT

iptables -P INPUT DROP

Note that user-defined chains does not have any effect for traffics that are not made to traverse them. Therefore, chains created earlier are not necessarily traversed earlier. Rule traversal starts from the base chains, and the one in concern is INPUT (in the filter table).
Also, you should really use ipset to "combine" -s rules.
One more example to show that rule order in a chain matters is, if you want some more sources to be (temporarily) allowed after running an iptables batch like the above, you cannot use -A to do it (unless you edit the batch and run it again, which flushes the respective table first). Instead you'll need to use -I. For example:
iptables -I ALLOW_TCP -s 6.7.8.9 -j TCP

because the rule must be earlier than:
iptables -A ALLOW_TCP -j ALLOW_ALL
iptables -A ALLOW_TCP -j TCP

so that the respective traffics won't be dropped unexpectedly by ALLOW_ALL.
